# build before restarting the node.js (express) server using Nodemon

Tags: node.js, express, babeljs, nodemon

I am using nodemon to watch the changes to the server files and restart the server. It works fine when the script is ec5

`nodemon ./server.js`

but I want to write the script in ec6 and compile using babel doing the same thing but building before the server is restarted.

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "babel src --out-dir dist",
    "serve": "npm run build && node dist/index.js", 
    "serve-dev": "nodemon dist/index.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "express": "^4.16.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.0.0-rc.1",
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0-rc.1",
    "@babel/node": "^7.0.0-rc.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0-rc.1",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.3"
  }
```

Comment: You can use `gulp` or `grunt` to automate the tasks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run with `babel-node`. (I can see it's already installed as dev dependency)

```
"serve-dev": "nodemon --exec babel-node src/index.js"
```

(assumed that `src/index.js` is your entry point of your app)

Answer (score 1):

I think `nodemon` has built-in support for this now.

1. Create a config file: https://github.com/remy/nodemon#config-files
2. Watch for the `restart` event and put your build script stuff there: https://github.com/remy/nodemon#triggering-events-when-nodemon-state-changes